# How to use __aiter__ in aiomultiprocessing

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

How can I use the **aiter**-method in the aiomultiprocessing?
I have a small code to download urls. They are directly available in the "get(url)"-function, but I need/want them in the "main()"-function.

Here a small code example:

```
Import aiomultiprocessing
Import requests_html

async def get(url):
        asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
        response = await asession.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        return soup

async def main():
    async with aiomultiprocess.Pool(processes=4, childconcurrency=8) as pool:
          await pool.map(get,urls) #--> What would be here the code to use them as they are ready?
```

I would be thankful for an example to use the **aiter**-method on the main()-function.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean something like this example? https://github.com/omnilib/aiomultiprocess#usage If not please give more details.

Comment: Yes, that was it.
Thank you.